# store textare event to a localStorage before pare reload

Tags: jquery, local-storage

is it possible to store a textarea event like 'keypress' to a localStorage so that when the page is refreshed, the textarea will have the same functionality?

```
$(".textareabox").on("keypress", function(evt){
 if(evt.which === 13){
   evt.preventDefault();
 }
});
```

I notice that when the div element, which holds the textarea, is appended to the body after a page refresh, the keypress event does not work anymore. I used localStorage to store the state. I can restore all the divs just fine, but Im having trouble making the keypress work. Thanks.

Comment: you are looking for delegation i guess, e.g: `$(document).on("keypress", ".textareabox", function(evt){...});`

Answer (score 0):

Try [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on("keypress",".textareabox", function(evt){ ..code here.. });
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```